# Javascript Errors: "No relay set", only in IE 7, 8

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, debugging, postmessage

My javascript won't load because of errors it receives, only in IE.  I used debugger to get the following errors.  This page renders the javascript correctly in Safari, FF and chrome but not in IE and only on specific pages like this.

http://tsqja.deznp.servertrust.com/Lakeside_721_2_Shelf_Heavy_Duty_Utility_Cart_p/lak-721.htm

1) No relay set (used as window.postMessage targetOrigin), cannot send cross-domain message

2) Invalid argument.   jquery.min.js

Any ideas what the first error implies?  I have switched out my jQuery build with the latest and it still does the same thing.

**UPDATE** I have updated my jquery.min.js to the latest and it I figured out this is where the page stops loading...after the invalid argument pops up in the jquery-latest.min.js, line 16 character 15511 which is the following letter 'b':

```
finally{b=[e,f],c=0}}return this}
```

Comment: Looking through the source for that link I see you're using Google's +1 button.  I'm currently trying to resolve a similar issue and Google Webmaster forums* doesn't appear to have a decent answer. Going to start a bounty for this. * http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Webmasters/label?lid=1f91cc0e87a8ed93&hl=en

Comment: Debug from the minified `jquery.min.js` is almost meaningless.  Try including the full `jquery.js` and sharing the debug from that.

Comment: IE7 does not support window.postMessage

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**DEMO** https://so.lucafilosofi.com/javascript-errors-no-relay-set-only-in-ie-7-8/

> - 1) - *No relay set (used as window.postMessage targetOrigin), cannot send cross-domain message*

is caused by the `<g:plusone />` button on your site: ( [google is busy of this notice](http://www.google.it/#sclient=psy&hl=it&source=hp&q=google+plusone++%3E+-+1%29+-+*No+relay+set+%28used+as+window.postMessage+targetOrigin%29,+cannot+send+cross-domain+message&pbx=1&oq=google+plusone++%3E+-+1%29+-+*No+relay+set+%28used+as+window.postMessage+targetOrigin%29,+cannot+send+cross-domain+message&aq=f&aqi=g-s1&aql=1&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=26689l28853l2l29289l9l7l4l0l0l0l476l1158l0.2.0.1.1l4l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=42fb80bd85d8273&biw=1536&bih=853) )
the only way i found to circumnvent this issue is by doing something like this:

```
$(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        gapi.plusone.render("plusone-div");
    },
    1500);

});
```

---

> - 2) - Invalid argument. jquery.min.js

looking into your source-code is a chaos! ;-) OMG

- you have lot's of errors <del>like ( missing `http://` protocol specified ):</del>
- different folder case-name like `/v/newsite/` and `/v/Newsite/`  this really matter if you are under nix but since you are using ASP...
- code like this `AttachEvent(window, 'load', store_init);` while using jquery like `jQuery(document).ready(function() {`
- multiple inclusion of the same file ( this file is included 3 times ) `/a/j/product_details.js`
- massive use of `$(function(){` & `$(document).ready(function(){` & `$(window).load(function(){` multiple times when just one needed;
- js `global`'s all around the page, at the top, in the middle and at the bottom, they should stay all on top IMHO...
- different version of jquery loaded at same time like: `jquery-1.4.4.min.js` & `jquery-1.6.2.js` & `1.4.2/jquery.min.js` together
- minor but always crappy, you have `<meta />` , `<link />` and `<script />` in mixed order just like a chicken salad, where they should stay in order meta, links and script preferably at the end of the page.
- missing semi-colon `;` all around;
- non-sense/malformed code like below and much much more...

---

```
if (!/\/shoppingcart\.asp/i.test(window.location.pathname)) {
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery('a').each(AddCartLink)
    });
}
```

---

```
var global_Config_EnableDisplayOptionProducts = 'False';
```

---

```
var global_ImageSeed = 'test.jpg';
global_ImageSeed = global_ImageSeed.substring(...
```

---

**your site with no errors:** https://so.lucafilosofi.com/javascript-errors-no-relay-set-only-in-ie-7-8/

what i have done is:

1. reordered main tags meta,links,script
2. <del>removed shitty widgets like addthis, google, facebook</del>
3. "tried" to place all the globals to the top;
4. commented the part of the code that cause chrome problems in the **TopScriptsTEST5.js** <sup>this file is your main problem</sup>, ( you should see an huge chunk of code commented )
5. removed duplicate file inclusion,
6. removed latest version of jquery, cause i strongly doubt that all the rest of your code work with the latest jquery version, so use the 1-4-4 instead
7. some other fix here and there... nothing special

---

hope this check-up help a little, but i think you need an exorcist ;-)

Comment: Jut a nitpick on your first point: Starting a url with // is perfectly fine, it will use the same scheme as the page it's on. Very handy if you have both http and https versions of your page and want to make sure to include absolute urls on the same protocol.

Comment: Good Stuff, thank you for the reply!  I am using a Volusion shopping cart, and unfortunately they throw all kinds of stuff in there that I cannot remove or even modify.  The ONLY code I have available which I myself created (which I edit basically everyday which is why it isnt MINIFIED right now) is the TopScripts (TopScriptsV2 right now).  But that's on my main site, www.BASequipment.com.  Most of the problems stated are Volusions own code and I cannot modify! Imagine that..

Comment: @ToddN: not quite true, ;) in your control-panel under `Design -> File Manager -> select-box -> vspfiles / templates / YOUR-THEME-ID / *.html, *.js` you can have some fun by editing the files theme ;) also remember that you should check and fix your TopScripts file as well.

Comment: @Michael Stum 'perfectly fine' on `file://` urls, too ? ;)